# TeamCity can't find Nuget

Tags: nuget, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a build set up on Team City but can't seem to get NuGet to restore the packages. My build configuration has two steps: Restore Nuget, then Build the solution. I have set up NuGet on TeamCity, so when I create a NuGet build step, I can choose a NuGet version from the drop down:
[image: My NuGet build step settings]

But when I build, it cant find NuGet:

Failed to find NuGet executable NuGet.CommandLine.3.3.0.nupkg. Check the version is listed in NuGet server settings tab.

Why cant it find NuGet?

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to install NuGet everytime you do a build?

Comment: No, I want to restore my nuget packages every time I build.

Comment: Yeah that you want to do, but not NuGet itself. I'm curious as to `NuGet Settings` it says `The path to NuGet.exe relative to the checkout directory` you have this set to `3.3.0` which I'm pretty sure isn't a relative path...

Comment: That field is a dropdown. Ill see if I can put an actual path there.

Comment: Can you share the build log / screen shots of the NuGet page in Administration?

Comment: Are there any warning/errors in teamcity-agent.log file on the agent that does not pock up NuGet? Are there NuGet.CommandLine.*.nupkg directories on this agent under the 
tools subdirectory?

Comment: It show's in your screen shots that you've set the default version to 3.4.3, but you're explicitly using version 3.3.0 in the NuGet Installer build runner- I agree it should be there based on the NuGet.exe tab in admin. Can you just humour me and choose DEFAULT in the NuGet Installer build runner drop down for the version and see what happens?